# Elementary 6.1 (Odin) and DNS issues

Tags: odin, apps

I am on my 3rd install of Odin (Elementary 6.1) each of the previous 2 installs have ended with a DNS issue (can not resolve names on internet but can ping anywhere).  None of the suggestions found here or elsewhere resolved anything.  The first install worked fine for 48 hours, the second for 72.  The only apps installed were ProtonVPN (a vpn obviously), Brave (browser) for both installs, on the second I added wire and telegram as communications apps (it was after wire and telegram that the DNS stopped).

This time, I will try a vanilla install, no changes other than adding my wifi password and changing the timezone, to see if it is an issue with my hardware or with the download (although I've run the updates).

Any known issues with ProtonVPN, Brave, Wire or Telegram that could cause the DNS issues?

Comment: As an additional note, I've had Elementary 4 (Loki) running for 3+ years as a good solid install on another laptop.  Would have gone with this again, but saw that 6 finally supported ProtonVPN installation.

Comment: So actually 6.1 is Joinr...and the issue seems to be with the ProtonVPN install.  Everything was solid for 3 days, until I installed the VPN...then BAM! no DNS